# Predict future payments using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

Considering a data set looking like the following, where the values correspond to the amount of money paid.

```
Name Age 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 
A    83  0    0    1000 900  550  0
B    24  550  550  0    0    0    0
C    35  0    0    0    0    700  500
D    63  0    0    0    400  0    0
E    17  0    0    0    0    0    1600
```

The goal is to predict how much still needs to be paid in the future for the listed people. We can assume that latest 3 years after the first payment there won't be anymore payments. (So I want to predict the payments for 2007 and 2008)

I was wondering what kind of machine learning algorithms/techniques would be suitable for this kind of problem?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Please clarify what these payments represent: are they supposed to follow some payment plan? If so do you have the full amount that they owe? Otherwise do people pay whatever they want whenever they can?